# Securing ClickOnce hosting at Amazon S3

Tags: clickonce, amazon-s3

I am hosting my ClickOnce deployment with Amazon S3. How can I secure (or restrict) only to my users (network). I was looking to see if I can restrict by IP but Amazon does not provide that with S3. Any recommendations? My users are all on a Windows domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider CloudFront Private content feature. Not only will you be able to serve your content more efficiently across multiple geographical locations but also it allows you to restrict access by IP. More info in our [blog post](http://blog.cloudberrylab.com/2009/11/managing-cloudfront-private-content.html)